# Rearrange numbers in the min and max form

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

Given the following input

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

We are suppose to sort the numbers so that they are sorted as following

```
[7,1,6,2,5,3,4]
```

So i figured i can basically create a new list and use two pointers one starting at left most index and the other starting at right most index. Since the list is already sorted the right pointer gives me the max value and left gives me the min value. So i basically keep on adding values of max and min and update the left pointer to move right and the right pointer to move left. Following is my solution.

```
def maxMin(lst):
    result = []
    left = 0
    right = len(lst) - 1
    while left < right:
        result.append(lst[right])
        result.append(lst[left])
        left += 1
        right -= 1
    if len(lst) % 2 != 0:
        result.append(lst[left])
    return result
```

While this solution works apparently this uses extra space and there is a possible way to come up with a solution that uses only constant space. I came across this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZRoVWxBngX0&t=202s) on youtube but i had no idea how the author came up with the solution. To me understanding the arrival at solution is more important than the actual solution. I would love if someone can shed some light.

Comment: hi Dinero, If this is that very special case, you can make it O(1), just push 7162534. If your list is arithmetic, then you may notice that every couple (v(i) + v(n-i) is a constant (here 8)) then a simple counter would do to regenerate the list. If the numbers are just in ascending order without much specificity (which is probably your case but not stated), then BoarGules answered you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extra space complained of is because you create a second list to hold the result. With a small amount of data that is an *entirely reasonable* way to go about it. But if your list had thousands of entries instead of a handful, then making a copy might not be feasible. In that case you might need to move the elements of the list *in place*.

We start by observing that the list is sorted and the elements in the last half of the list get moved to earlier in the list, at even-numbered positions (0, 2, 4). So, first calculate how many elements have to be shifted to earlier in the list. Then, for each of the elements to be shifted, calculate its new position (0, 2, 4) and move it there.

The first element to be shifted is at the end of the list. After it has been moved to an earlier point, the next element to be shifted is now at the end of the list. So the item to be moved is always the last in the list, and that can be extracted using `pop()`.

Like this:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
shifts = len(a)//2
for i in range(shifts):
    print(f"shifting {a[-1]} to position {i*2}")
    a.insert(i*2,a.pop())
print (a)
```

Output from the last `print()` call is `[7, 1, 6, 2, 5, 3, 4]`. The `print()` call inside the loop is simply there to show you what is happening.

This alternative way of doing it trades execution time for space. Every time you insert an element in a list, other than at the end, all of the subsequent elements have to be moved to the right to make room. That does a lot of processing behind your back, even though it is a single line of code.

Answer (score 1):

There is a sort in place strategy that minimizes memory movements (I believe inserting in a list reallocates it internally).  It is based on a naive sort algorithm that swaps the value at each position with the subsequent position having the lowest value.  With a small adjustment to the logic, we can make the sort decide that each position will alternatively swap the lowest and highest value depending on whether the position is odd or even.

This sort-in place will perform N swaps and N*(N-1)/2 comparisons so the memory overhead will be minimal and there will be no reallocation.

```
def updownSort(a):
    for i in range(len(a)-1):         # for each position except the last one
        p=i                           # identify the swapping position (p)
        for j in range(i+1,len(a)):        # only look in remaining positions
            if bool(i&1) == (a[p]>a[j]):   # alternate seeking the largest and smallest value
                p = j
        a[p],a[i] = a[i],a[p]              # make the swap with the index that was found

a =  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

updownSort(a)
print(a)
# [7, 1, 6, 2, 5, 3, 4]
```

Note that any other "sort in place" algorithm (e.g. bubble sort) could be adapted in the same fashion as long as the comparisons can take into account the positions being compared in addition to the values.